# What's the best practice for watching for finished video encodes?

Tags: node.js, video, encoding, adobe-premiere, chokidar

## TL;DR

I'm unsure the best way to recognise when encoding videos have finished with Chokidar. Given the different methods encoders build their video files, what's the best way to accomodate all of them?

## Context

I've developed a workflow for our office that allows us to quickly queue encode jobs in Adobe Premiere Pro. To queue them locally, I made use of Premiere's CEP API. I can easily send a job to Adobe Media Encoder (on the same machine) and it will automatically encode the video file to the relative project directory. This works great.

To queue encode jobs onto LAN workstations, I've taken a different approach, as the CEP API doesn't allow for any extensibility beyond the local machine. Instead I made use of Adobe Media Encoder's watch folders to detect added Premiere project files to a subfolder on our NAS (everything is on the NAS). This works great too.

Unfortunately, I'm unaware of a way for the queued encodes to be output to the relative project directory in the same way queuing locally does. I'm trying to find a way to do this by watching a common directory and moving finished files.

Since each video filename I'm queuing has this structure:
*"projectName_sequenceName_givenName_renderType.mp4/.mxf"* I've been able to move the files with this information easily. However, I'm struggling to accomodate for the different methods different encoding processes use. Different encoders - X264, MainConcept H264, etc - encode to disk differently.

### Using Chokidar, I watched how different encoders build their files:

**Example #1:**

If I start a *DnXHR MXF* encode, it will first create the final .MXF container and then fill it. When it finishes, it writes the sidecar .XMP file. If the encode fails or is cancelled, the sidecar file will not be written.

**Example #2:**

If I start a *TMPG x264* encode, it will first create the final .mp4 container, then create a temporary file: '.mp4_00_' appended. It will then write some initial metadata to the final container, start encoding to the '.mp4_00_' and depending on file size, create additional temporary files, '_.mp4_01_', etc. Finally it writes some additional information to the container, then to the temporary files and then deletes the temporary files. If the encode fails or is cancelled, the files are deleted.

**Example #3:**

If I start a *MainConcept H264 encode* (Premiere's default), it will first create the audio temp file, in this case '.aac'. Then create another temp file '.mkv.md0'. Halfway through encoding, it will create the video container '.m4v', start encoding to that, create some more temporary files '.md7/md6', create the final container '.mp4', along with 'sbjo.tmp', copy the '.mkv' file and '.aac' into the '.mp4' container, add a '*00*' file, very quickly delete it and then finish writing the '.mp4' metadata. Some of this happens very quickly and Chokidar has not always picked it up. Unless the encoder is being inconsistent.

These are the three encode types I've observed, and they're the three we need and use. I suppose I could watch each of them differently, but my concern would be if we ever switched encoders, I'd have to rewrite the code to accomodate them. The watch folder feature that Adobe Media Encoder has recognises when files have finished encoding before attempting to use them. I haven't tested every format, but a good deal. Would Media Encoder be accomodating each unique encoding process? Simply polling locked files? Or is there something I'm missing?

The code I have currently works fine for DNxHR MXFs provided they don't fail or are cancelled. It struggles with the h264/x264 examples. Since the file is created and left untouched while encoding to the temporary files, chokidar will register 'add'. Since the file is locked the move fails. Obviously this works fine when simply copying or moving a finished video file.

```
const watcher = chokidar.watch(['Z:/NETWORKRENDER/Finished/*.{mp4,mxf}'], {
    persistent: true,
    // On start, works on existing files
    ignoreInitial: false, 
    followSymlinks: true,      
    interval: 1000,
    awaitWriteFinish: {
        stabilityThreshold: 5000,
        pollInterval: 20000
    },
  });
```